# CSS selector select all img tags inside a div irrespective of child level

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select all `img` tags inside a `div`, so that a common `CSS` can be applied to it.

I don't know the level to which `img` tag can be for example

```
<div class="my_div">
   <div>
      <p>
         <img src="x"/>
      </p>
      <img src="y"/>
      <p>
        <a>
           <img src="z"/>
        </a>
     </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this structure can change as it is dynamic in nature only constant is top div `my_div`. I want to apply css on all `img` as:

```
{
  max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Any ideas how can it be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried  `.my_div img`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
.my_div img
{
   max-width:100%;
}
```

if this doesn't applies then use `!important` like this

```
.my_div img
{
   max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add CSS for all img then you can use

```
img{max-width:100% !important;}
```

and if you want to target an img inside of a div so you can just add class name before the img tag

```
.my_div img{max-width:100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.my_div div img
{
  max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I would remove that second div from the selector: *this structure can change as it is dynamic in nature only constant is top div my_div*

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
div.my_div img
{    
  //CSS goes here    
  // Like - width:300px;    
}
```

This ensure that it is applied to "all the images" in the Div having class "my_div"

Answer (score 0):

for CSS in angular component:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mydiv img { 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

for CSS in index page:

```
body ::ng-deep .mydiv img{
  background-color: green;
}
```